# SQL statement is executed but not effectuated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, alter, sql-server-profiler

Website with an underlying SQL 2012 database:

An ALTER TABLE for adding a column is executed. The website is setup for using an SQL-account (we'll call it myAccount), and this account is db_owner.

The statement is

```
ALTER TABLE [ItemType_Website_Settings] ADD [myNumber] INT NULL DEFAULT(0)
```

The ALTER TABLE statement **is registered by SQL Profiler with a BatchCompleted**. But refreshing the table, the column has not been created.

Also

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE 'myNumber'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

does not give any records.

BUT:
Going to SQL Management Studio, using the before mentioned SQL-account "myAccount", and executing the same ALTER TABLE from here, the column is created just fine..?

Any clues? I'm totally lost here.

Thanx in advance for your input.

-- RESOLVED --
Profiler got the batch, but it was never committed.

Best regards
Morten Snedker

Comment: Are you using transactions?

Comment: "effectuated", great word. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/effectuated, probably not quite what you mean though but I understand.

Comment: any triggers on the table?

Comment: Transaction was the keyword. Missing log of Rollback was the mischief. 

And had I just kept the transaction-info when profiling, I'd discovered it. But thanks for putting me back on track! :)

Comment: @ Jodrell - It was "effectuated" as in http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/effectuate   ;-)

Comment: @MortenSnedker As soon as I saw the question I thought a missing commit would be the cause.  You should add that as an answer and mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the Issue of uncommitted transaction you have to commit your transaction after Alter table statement executed .